# Is there any way I can get information about UI components of an activity through a Service?

Tags: android, service

I am working on an application where a service runs continuously in the background. I want to determine the UI components of the `activity` which is in foreground. I am using `AccessibilityService` for determining the current Activity. I am able to get the `packageName` and `activityName` of the current activity. I know that the UI information can be extracted through `getWindow()` function ,but this function is not available inside `Service` class. I have searched a lot and couldn't find a solution for it. Just wanted to make sure that is there a way to get UI information about the current `Activity` inside a `Service`?

Comment: You might want to bind the activity to the service...then display the data from the service and talk with the service directly

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I have no control of the activity in my case.